# Installing US International Keyboard Layout in Mountain Lion

Tags: keyboard

How can I install US International Keyboard Layout in Mountain Lion (step by step, please!)?

Answer (score 1):

OS X comes with a version of the layout preinstalled, but it just has to be enabled in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: Hi Lauri, I did this. but it's just not working. When I press the ` key I get the British key. exactly the key you see under escape key(ESC): http://parkernet.com/applepro/images/wireless-british.jpg

Comment: @Alex I also think that someone changed the key caps based on the photo in [your question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74615/mountain-lion-us-keyboard-layout-bug-british-layout-when-selected-us-keyboar).

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at this link, it really helped me:

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/keyboards/mackey.html

Comment: Can you describe the contents of the link? We prefer answers that contain content, not just links.