# Mountain Lion US keyboard layout .. bug? British layout when selected US keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, text, internationalization, language

When I change my input source to US Keyboard and I want to press this key: ` I get some British key.

My keyboard is this one:

[image]

And it behaves like this one:

[image]

I changed my keyboard layout like described in this: [stackexchange post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/62082/36463) but there is nothing changed. When I press the ` key I get that symbol as on British keyboard.

In result it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Is that your keyboard layout in the picture? You can determine your actual layout using this page: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2841?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Hi Gerry, I edited my post just now. thank you. but I don't don't think you understand my problem

Comment: What do you get when you press Shift + 3?  If it is #, then you are just getting the ISO (European or International) version of the American (ANSI) US keyboard layout, and it means your machine has mistaken the "keyboard type".

Comment: PS Go to system preferences/language & text/input sources an check the box for Show Input Menu in Menu Bar.  Then look at the top right of your screen and tell us what flag you see.  If it is the US flag with PC at the bottom, switch it to just plain US flag.

Comment: Tom. I get # and under settings I have U.S. keyboard (without PC). it's the only one selected. there is no pc or something... Do you know how can I change it?

Comment: @alex Where did you get this machine?  The keyboard is not right.  The key next to the z should not have < > on it, which you see are duplicated on comma and period.

Comment: :) I just noticed that.. I bought it from my country from a store like ebay.. from some other guy... I guess my `~ should be replaced and maybe he bought the laptop from abroad.. so... thank you a lot.. lol..

Comment: @alex  As far as I know, there is no country which uses a keyboard like that.  I think someone replaced some of the keys with different ones.  It should have keys like those in the picture you first posted about how it behaves.  The key to the right of "/' also looks wrong.

Comment: hi Tom. you are right. thank you for your help. for sure some keys were replaced. I don't understand the reason but it's fine for me at the moment. at least I know what's different and I know how to use my keyboard. I don't look at it anyway.. but I wanted it perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your keyboard has been modified and is non-standard.  If for some reason you want what is printed on the keys to match up with what is typed, you could make a custom keyboard layout using

http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele